# How can I Ctrl + A on emacs?

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I'm new to emacs, how can I highlight all text and copy on emacs?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Jv1.png)

Comment: Ctrl-A works fine, but does something different than you expect. C-x h marks the whole buffer. Going forward, probably consult the documentation before asking.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>h</kbd> runs the command `mark-whole-buffer` (select all)
- <kbd>M-w</kbd> runs the command `kill-ring-save` (copy)

As with many programs, you can find both "Select All" and "Copy" in the `Edit` menu -- where you can also see the aforementioned key bindings being advertised.

Answer (score 0):

As **phils** said, you can find it in the `Edit` menu, with the main keyboard shortcut `C-x` `h`.

Furthermore, you can see ALL the key bindings by typing `ctrl-h` `k` and then clicking menu `Edit` > `Select All`, leading emacs to open an `*Help*` buffer containing:

```
<menu-bar> <edit> <mark-whole-buffer> runs the command mark-whole-buffer (found in global-map)

It is bound to s-a, C-x h, <menu-bar> <edit> <mark-whole-buffer>.
```

You may notice the key binding `s-a` which means `super-a` (thanks **phils**) and, on the mac, refers to the standard shortcut `cmd-a` (press and hold the `cmd` modifier and type the letter `a`).

Otherwise, on any emacs, you may also type `M-x` `mark-whole-buffer` `RET` (which can be useful if you want to insert in an emacs-lisp function) or the sequence `M-<` `C-x` `SPACE` `M->` (which can be useful if you want to skip the first line of the buffer for example).

Comment: For clarity, the `s` modifier is "super" and isn't a MacOS-specific thing (but not all systems/keyboards will have it available by default).